# Black screen after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: xorg, 13.10

Just upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and all I got was a black screen. The hardware I'm running is Asus Zenbook UX31A (Intel GPU).

I do hear that the login screen drums do play, so the system does boot to login screen. When I try to boot using kernel 3.11.0-12 recovery mode, it tells me "initctl: event failed". Then if I go on an press ctrl+alt+f2, log in and command startx, it dies because "Fatal server error: no screens found". Here are some logs from /var/log/Xorg.0.log http://pastebin.com/ZQasUKJx

Kernel 3.8.0-31 work ok, as did things before the upgrade.

Comment: I had an acer netbook. The upgrade took forever and I ended up with said black screen. I didn't bother with all the above complexities. Instead made a 13.10 live boot stick and installed wiping out 13.04. Worked like a charm. Only down side had to reget extras I had before like a video editor I like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a kernel bug, as reported here:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=167463

Quick solution is to switch to BIOS mode instead of UEFI mode.
= Disable Secure Boot and enable "Launch CSM".

You can peruse the Archlinux thread above if you want a more permanent fix and you feel like patching the kernel yourself.  I don't consider myself technically good enough to do that safely (or quickly), so I'm putting up with running in BIOS mode for now and waiting until another Kernel is released.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Never done any kernel patching before, but weekend is coming and it is not like I have any better things to do ;)

Comment: @Harri I'm facing the same. ANy simpler solutions?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/365735/13-10-saucy-login-issues-since-update-from-13-04-boots-in-to-text-mode/366583?noredirect=1#comment480521_366583

Comment: Install kernel 3.12 and use that http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/linux-kernel-3-12-released-install-ubuntu-or-linux-mint/

Answer (score 2):

It is a known bug ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1229686 ) with medium priority (althought this bug leaves the system unusable for people).
If you set your system as affected in launchpad you will get status updates regarding this issue.

Set the compatibility mode (as mentioned by user203894) is one solution or just use an older kernel (max 3.9.9).

Comment: Can also install fixed kernel packages from the duplicate bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1195483/comments/72