# Ubuntu 13.10 won't boot and hangs on a black screen

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit today and I sat on the internet most of the day after installation. I shut the computer down and went bowling with my family. When I came back, I turned on my computer and it came to the boot screen as usual, but then the screen went black and stayed black. Can this be solved or do I have to install Ubuntu 13.04. My dad does not know about this and I do not want to get yelled at for an hour, so I need an answer before midnight mountain time, otherwise I will install Ubuntu 13.04 so I won't get yelled at in the morning.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is this still reproducible at least?

Comment: Probably not, he was last seen in November.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, one of the programs must be the cause. I reinstalled Ubuntu and I did not install any programs, I just rebooted after logging in. It came to the login just fine. You need to install one program at a time until you get to that one program that makes the whole OS go screwy. That is my only suggestion, I hope this helps.

Comment: I repeated my steps and when I got to disabling the guest account I didn't type 'sudo echo allow-guest=false >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf' I typed 'sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf' and I got a blank text edit window. So lightdm.conf is either empty or does not exist in this new OS.

Comment: the real command is this: sudo sh -c 'echo "allow-guest=false" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf'

Answer (score 1):

You don't really give enough information to diagnose fully, but your symptoms sound like this issue, which can be solved by switching from UEFI to legacy BIOS mode:

[Black screen after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360412/black-screen-after-upgrading-from-13-04-to-13-10)
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=167463

Answer (score 1):

I had sorta same issue.

Have Lenovo W520. Put the video card to be in discrete mode and disabled optimus from BIOS.

I installed ubuntu 13.10 64bit and the computer would hang. Nvidia 304 or 319 alike...

I then put 'acpi_backlight=vendor' onto the the linux line (the one refering to vmlinuz), and the boot never hanged. hope this helps somebody!

Comment: A bit more in-depth explaination how to do it would have been nice. Like [in this example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/128463/how-to-control-brightness/128471#128471)

Comment: Also Lenovo W520 issues with 13.10. I'm still looking for the complete solution, but this bit of code made my system boot normally again. I used Grub Customizer and added this to the line you mention, at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are on a time constraint my advise would be to simply re-install. Otherwise you will have to troubleshoot your system to find out the problem. It may be a simple fix but there is no guarantee. In the future you should test the upgrade using a LiveCD. Take this as a lesson.

Comment: I did test it from the live CD, maybe hitting the upgrade instead of replace 13.04 was a bad choice. How do I trouble shoot the system? Do I need the grub menu for that? Because it doesn't show up. Thanks your answer helped out

Comment: To troubleshoot I would need more info on the hardware you are running. If you where able to run the LiveCD without a problem then you will most likely not have a problem with installing 13.10 from there.

Comment: Here is a link to check out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360688/i-upgraded-from-12-04-to-12-10-but-when-i-log-in-the-screen-is-blank

The user here had to restart the computer and then enter the command prompt... CTRL + ALT + (F1 or F2)
Then issue the command: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: It won't boot at all even after formatting the hard drive and installing a fresh copy. I installed Google chrome, Google Earth, and the facebook desktop app. I also typed sudo echo allow-guest=false >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf. I used the unity music lens to listen to avenged sevenfold songs on sound cloud and got on facebook. I created 2 standard users (brian and guest). could any of these cause problems in Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit?

Comment: my hardware is: Intel DQ965GF Motherboard (OS independant), Intel core 2 64-bit, 12GB HHD (SATA), 200GB HHD (SATA, installed here), 250GB HHD (SATA, Encrypted with LUKS), 3GB RAM (DIMM 0 A 1024MB,DIMM 1 A 524MB, DIMM 0 B 1024MB, DIMM 1 B 524MB),2 Rewritable DVD drives (one SATA and one IDE), small floppy drive and car reader, and AMD gallium 0.4. That's all I know from the top of my head, I have no OS to give me more info on the graphics card, but all Ubuntu OSs worked on my PC from 12.04-13.04 just fine. Does this mean  will never be able to use Ubuntu 13.10? I think I am screwed.

Comment: Were exactly does it stop when you boot? Do you get anything after the BIOS post?

Comment: the BIOS shows up then it comes to a purple screen that is blank for 20 seconds, then the screen goes black. 10 seconds later the moniter enters power save mode due to the computer not responding.

Comment: And when you press CTRL + ALT + (F1 or F2) you get nothing? You should be able to get to a command prompt where you can issue commands. A similar thing happened to me when upgrading from 10.10.

Comment: I did a dual boot with 12.04, so after the update I will boot to 13.10 and try it

Comment: ok ctrl+f2 got me to the terminal and everything is timing out, if I have to login I might be screwed.

Comment: so I can't log on to terminal I get messages saying that everything fails

Comment: I will leave 12.04 on it and hope my dad doesn't notice and try again after he leaves for work. thanks for your help.