# 13.10 Saucy login issues since update from 13.04 - boots in to text mode

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.10

I tried updating from 13.04 to 13.10, it upgraded with errors. I'm not sure of the errors it faced while updating. I have Nvidia NVS 300 graphics card.

On reboot my system stuck on splash screen. No recovery options or older kernel attempts succeed.  Edited grub to bypass plymouth and have text based screen. It boots well on text based screen.

tried updating grub and fixing configuration files with dpkg but all fails.

HAL was creating issues. I removed HAL. And removed pid file once.

**UPDATE:**
System passes splash screen but boots into text mode after failure of GDM and lightgdm. I have installed nvidia-current. Any further solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some packages did not configure correctly. What happens if you run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

on the text based interface you get to after starting? That command should go through and complete the configuration of all packages.

If it doesn't work, what is the error message?

Comment: it repaired mktexslr in first attempt and a folder under /etc/ updated. But that has not resolved the issue. Performing the command again gave a blank output.

Comment: Is there anything illuminating in your log files? For example, what does /var/log/kern.log and /var/log/syslog say?

Comment: logs say too much. One thing I found in /var/log/syslog is "Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' "

Comment: after splash screen I get - cdc_acm can not make call on its own. Device is not a modem. 

And system turns to text mode